# Newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 on AMD feels slow

Tags: drivers, 16.04, 64-bit, browser, amd-processor

Since my old laptop got fried, I bought a new laptop on a budget for simple browsing and decided to go with Ubuntu. However, the new laptop feels as slow, if not slower than my old one. That just doesn't seem right. Is there any way to make sure I installed everything correctly and what commands could I use to figure out my problem?

The laptop in itself feels fine, new applications start quickly enough, but opening a new tab in a browser (tried FF, chrome, chromium) takes about 3-4 seconds. It just feels so sluggish.

This is my first time using *nix on my home laptop but I have used ubuntu, openSuse, fedora and a few others at my university, so I am familiar with the terminal itself, just not the specifics to administrate my own laptop. Picked ubuntu because I liked the style, simple as that. I really only need my laptop for light/older gaming (think LoL, Sims, CIV and the like, AMD shouldn't be a problem here) streaming tv series and surfing the web (although I am the type to use 50+ tabs).

The laptop is an HP 255 G5 with an AMD A6-7310 with 4x 2.0 GHz, 8 GB Ram and a 1TB HDD. Connection is at ~35 Mbps.

I installed ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS from a DVD (downloaded it yesterday from the official website), restarted, updated and restarted, looked for drivers (found one for an unknown device) and that's pretty much it. Installed FF, Chrome, Chromium and ran across the sluggishness on all three. Thought firejail might have something to do with it, but seems to not make much of a difference.

How can I figure out if it's something I did or the laptop itself (so I can ship it the hell back and add 50 bucks for a better laptop)? Besides just installing another distribution or win7 (have a key from my university), are there any diagnostic commands I can run? Anything else you need to know?

---

**Edit:**

Answers and comments helped with the slowness but not significantly. Installed win7 just for comparison, did not have the same sluggishness but still not quite what I was looking for. Laptop itself would have been fine, just didn't seem to want to work with Ubuntu properly.

Shipped laptop back, added a bit of money and bought an ASUS with Intel.

**If you run across something similar**, I suggest checking your Ubuntu installation. Mine may or may not have been corrupted during one of my installs, as I found out while trying to install ubuntu on the ASUS. Borrowed a USB stick and installed from USB instead. May or may not have helped with initial problem as well, however I saw no error message indicating a faulty installation on the first laptop.

Comment: Return it and get a laptop with an Intel CPU and either integrated graphics or NVIDIA. AMD graphics don't have drivers on 16.04, and AMD is generally weaker than Intel anyway.

Comment: As far as I have read, missing drivers is not really a problem for daily use unless you actually need quality graphics which I don't. Although your "AMD is generally weaker" statement might not be true for my budget, your suggestion is what I was planning to do if all else fails. However, getting a comparable INTEL costs me a bit more.  So I'd love to see if there is something wrong first.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you did do something wrong. AMD is weaker, even at the budget level. I can barely watch videos on my AMD card (luckily it's a server and not a main computer) on 16.04, as they cut out, freeze or glitch. I haven't even tried to game yet. I'm not sure about more current chips, since I've only had mine a year, but I did have a laptop where the AMD graphics severely degraded after a few years, forcing me to get a new laptop. For that reason (longevity), I also recommend Intel.

Comment: What is your swap file size? That's important.

Comment: Swap seems to be 7.5 GB. Did not tinker with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening tabs on mine is in a milisecond to couple of milliseconds latency.  Instantaneous in other words.
Questions:

1) What sort of HDD do you have? SSD?
      A SSD will significantly increase the performance of your laptop if you have a mechanical one!  Sell you HDD if it is mechanical and use that to get a SSD.

2) **sudo apt update && sudo apt install preload;**
      Preload will learn what you open and run the most and preload them into volatile cache in ram.

3) Did you play around with swappiness by any chance?  Increasing swappiness can give the feeling of latency if stuff usually in ram is all of a sudden in the swap. If the swap is in a mechanical hdd and not a ssd, it would be even worse. Swappiness defaults are the best from my experience.

4) Don't shutdown but go to suspend instead. Doing so preserves stuff in memory (ram) for faster access when you restart your session including your cached application usage.

Try and address all of the above.  If not try point 2 at least.

Comment: 1.) It is a mechanical HDD, not an SSD. Thoughtit wasn't in the budget, seems like I'll have to make some room for it anyway.

2) Done and done. No change.

3)I stayed away from swap since I had read that it might not be the best idea to fuss around with it. 

4) Not really related to the problem, though? Thank you anyway, will keep this in mind.

Comment: Preload doesn't work straight away, it needs to learn how u use the computer before it can preload into ram. In other words, open the browser multiple times and it should start to get snappy. The longer your pc is running and you interacting with it the better it gets. Hence why point 4 above. Another thing about point 4, when you suspend, you preserve your cache

Comment: Disk speed is a good test. Type:"sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda". On my SDD for example it gets: "Timing cached reads:   11392 MB in  2.00 seconds = 5699.93 MB/sec ###  Timing buffered disk reads: 1568 MB in  3.00 seconds = 522.25 MB/sec"

Comment: Ok, I'll try to let preload work for another day or so, but can I really expect 3 seconds out of it? 

hdparm gives the following: 
Timing cached reads:   2958 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1478.96 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 284 MB in  3.01 seconds =  94.38 MB/sec

Seems rather low, doesn't it? Have to look up some benchmarks...

Comment: Also, the more ram you have, the more things get cached by preload.  Consider bumping up to 16GB if the budget allows. If that's coupled with a SSD then they would be complementing each other which would be even better.

Comment: @MSchu, how is it going to date?  Did any of the recommendations work?

Comment: I saw a slight uptick in performance but ultimately nothing that made me want to stay with that laptop. Still took way to long to simply open new tabs. Am shipping it back, bought a pricier Intel, still setting it up since I seem to have to fiddle with Intel Skylake quite a bit, but it is much more to my pleasure. Thanks a lot for your help, though!

Comment: Also, my ubuntu installation may have been faulty, ran across problems while installing it on second laptop. Not sure if that would have fixed the initial problem.

Comment: @DanglingPointer, accepted your answer for helpful insights and slight increase on speed, even though the problem was still there.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  Out of curiosity though did you get an SSD this time around?

Comment: I did indeed. 128GB SSD was the same price as most 1TB HDD. at the higher price range for laptops. Since I have two external 2TB HDD, that was an easy decision to make. No upgrade on the RAM though, still 8GB.